# phpmyadmin - foreign key is updated with primary key value when data is inserted

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a two tables: venue and space.  Venue has a primary key venueid and space has a foreign key that references venue (venueid).

I have altered the tables to add the foreign key constraint and attempted to link them in relation view but nothing seems to be working.

Data is inserted into these two tables at the same time.  **My aim is that once data is inserted into the two tables that the value in venue(venueid)PK matches the value in space(venueid)FK so that I do not have to update them manually.**

Please help.

[image]

Comment: So, in your mind, what are foreign keys used for? I'm asking because you are aiming to achieve something in completely backwards order.

Comment: Am I?  Thanks you might be able to clarify this for me.  I have a registration form that inserts into two tables.  I want the primary key of one to match the foreign key of the other so that I can select rows from both tables where venueid matches.  Am I doing this wrong?  Thanks

Comment: It's not `primary key` that matches `foreign key`. It's the other way around. You insert into your first table (`venue`), you retrieve what PK value was generated (`LAST_INSERT_ID()` function in MySQL), and then you insert into `spaces` table specifying the value of FK to match `PK` value. This process **is** manual. Purpose of foreign keys is to enforce data integrity, which means you can't have a reference in `spaces` to `venues` if that `venues` record doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok thank you.  That is my exact understanding also.  So where you say this process is manual - is there no way to change this?  So that when a PK is created it updates the FK column automatically?

Comment: You can use triggers to achieve that sort of automation, but if PK is *created*, nothing can be updated to that PK because it just got generated. If you want to insert something in `spaces` table when record gets added to `venues`, it's doable, however it's unknown what kind of info you want to mark down. Doing this via triggers will probably be limited when it comes to which exact information you'll insert.

Comment: Venueid(PK) in venues is set to auto increment once a new row is added.  I would like that value to automatically go into venueid(FK) of spaces as a row in spaces is created the same time as a row in venues.  That way the record matches.